# Reverse display order of css grid columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with a list of links displayed in a single row like a toolbar

`a | b | c | d | e | f | g`

is it possible as with flexbox to reverse this order

`g | f | e | d | c | b | a`

based on a specific screen size or should i stick with flexbox

https://codepen.io/hanakin/pen/wvKjgpx?editors=1100

```css
.wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 56px auto;
}

.c-bar {
  background-color: #343a40;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: calc(7 * 56px);
}

.c-action {
  color: #868e96;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
}
.c-action:hover, .c-action:focus {
  background-color: #495057;
  outline: 0;
  color: #008dff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <section>
  <h5>Bar grid Tests</h5>
  <div class="c-bar">
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    A
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    B
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    C
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    D
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    E
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    F
   </a>
   <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    G
   </a>
  </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change the direction:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 56px auto;
}

.c-bar {
  background-color: #343a40;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: calc(7 * 56px);
  direction: rtl; /* added*/
}

.c-action {
  color: #868e96;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
}

.c-action:hover,
.c-action:focus {
  background-color: #495057;
  outline: 0;
  color: #008dff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <section>
    <h5>Bar grid Tests</h5>
    <div class="c-bar">
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    A
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    B
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    C
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    D
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    E
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    F
   </a>
      <a class="c-bar-item c-action" href="#">
    G
   </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing direction will cause accessibility issues, change text-align etc. The web will be probably broken for rtl readers.